# UITextField text property returns random integer

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield

When I try to get the text of a UITextField it returns a random integer. Here's the code I used:

```
NSLog(@"Field Text: %d", field.text);
```

`field` being the UITextField. And in the debugger it returns an random number, for example `29876208` when there is text in the UITextField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euhm, I think you are either getting back some kind of representation of the memory address the text is located, or just some bull-sh*t.

You should try to do this:

```
NSLog(@"Field text : %@", field.text);
```

The problem is the formatter you are using.

Comment: Thanks very much! I didn't know there were different formatters. So simple!